# Send form variables to mail template using phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-templates

I am trying to pass 2 form variables to echo them in a mail template i.e. get name/mail from form, send using phpmailer and display in template.
Below is my form :

```
<form id=beta-subscribe method="post" class="wow fadeIn animated" role=form data-wow-offset=10 data-wow-duration=1.5s>
     <div class=input-group>
        <input type=text id=subscriber-name name=yourname placeholder="Your name" class=form-control />
        <input type=email id=subscriber-mail name=mail placeholder="Your email address" class=form-control />
    </div>
<span class=input-group-btn>    
    <button class="xyz">Subscribe</button>
</span>
```

Below is my phpmailer code to send the variables.

```
?php
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$name = $_POST['yourname'];
function is_email_valid($email) {
return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}  

if ( isset($email) && is_email_valid($email) ) {
   file_put_contents("abc.txt", "$email\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
   require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
   ob_start();
   $_GET['receiverEmail'] = $email;
   $_GET['receiverName'] = $name;
   $_GET['key'] = base64_decode('SKJNJKFKJD');
   include('abcd/abcde.php');
   include $name;
   $body = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();

   $mail = new PHPMailer;
   $mail->isHTML(true);
   $mail->Body = $body;
```

And this is my php mail template

```
<?php
define('SECURITY_KEY', base64_decode('LKJFNJKKJD='));

if(isset($_GET['receiverEmail']) && isset($_GET['key']) && isset($_GET['receiverName'])){
  $receiverEmail = $_GET['receiverEmail'];
  $key = $_GET['key'];
  $name = $_GET['receiverName'];
}else{
   header('location: WEBSITE');
}
if($key!=SECURITY_KEY)
 header('location: WEBSITE');

?>

<!doctype html>
</html>
```

This just dosen't seem to work! Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated as I am relatively new to php.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you have any stacktrace?

Comment: This is very strange code. Why are you putting things into `$_GET`? Quote your HTML attributes.

Comment: Just got it to work. I was calling the wrong ajax POST variable- it should have been 'name' instead of 'yourname'...